# Как использовать Callback?

Tags: kotlin, callback, retrofit2

У меня есть слушатель внутри адаптера. При зажатии элемента - происходит запрос на сервер. Как мне реализовать обновление данных в адаптере после запроса на сервер?
**viewholder.bind**

```
fun bind(listItem: Comment) {
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener {

            if (pref.getToken() == null)
                showDialog()

            if (pref.getToken() != null) {
                mService = Common.retrofitServices
                mService.patchCommentById(
                    listItem.id,
                    pref.getToken()!!,
                    createJsonRequestBody("approved_comment" to (!listItem.approved_comment).toString())
                )?.enqueue(object : Callback<Comment> {
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<Comment>, response: Response<Comment>) {
                        ivHasApproved.setImageResource(if ((response.body() as Comment).approved_comment) R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_24 else R.drawable.ic_baseline_clear_24)
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<Comment>, t: Throwable) {
                        Log.e("retrofit-module", "attempt to approve has been crashed: $t")
                    }
                })
            }

            return@setOnLongClickListener true
        }
    }
```

**функция из активити, где заполняю адаптер**

```
private fun getAllCommentsList() {
    mService.getCommentsByPostId(post.id).enqueue(object : Callback<MutableList<Comment>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<MutableList<Comment>>,
            response: Response<MutableList<Comment>>
        ) {
            adapter = CommentListAdapter(response.body() as MutableList<Comment>)
            adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            activity_post_rv_comments.adapter = adapter
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<MutableList<Comment>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("retrofit-module", "comments bad request: $t")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Мое мнение, что неправильно у пользователя под пальцем что-то менять. А технически так же как и при любом другом действии пользователя: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` для уже существующего адаптера.

Comment: Этот пользователь - я. Метод `notifyDataSetChanged()` недоступен из слушателя `onLongClickListener`.

Comment: Значит слушатель должен кому-то, у кого он доступен, сказать чтобы его вызвал. О пользователе что я хотел донести, когда делаете вещи, которые обычно никто не делает, не стоит ожидать что с этим вам кто-то поможет. Просто потому что ваш вопрос может быть непонятен.

Comment: Не понимаю. В этом и заключается вопрос, как бы. Слушатель внутри ViewHolder'a, которому недоступен адаптер. `О пользователе что я хотел донести, когда делаете вещи, которые обычно никто не делает, не стоит ожидать что с этим вам кто-то поможет. Просто потому что ваш вопрос может быть непонятен.` - спасибо, я пересмотрю подход к решению такой задачи, только мне действительно интересно как в рамках текущих условий такая задача может решиться, чтобы лучше понять архитектуру.

Comment: Вы же нам показали только два метода в вакууме, тут сложно что-то сказать о из взаимодействии.

Comment: В конструкторе метода bind Вашего ViewHolder добавьте что-то вроде private val callback: ()->Unit = {} и вызывайте в нужном месте callback.invoke()
А в адаптере это будет как лямбда: `myViewHolder.bind(commentItem){ //вот здесь обрабатываем нажатие и можем обновить данные }`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я решил проблему обновления данных в адаптере путем реализации класса с интерфейсом OnItemTouchListener, в нем и управляю выделенными элементами.